# Having Problem with React-native-gesture-handler(cannot find symbol String overflow = ((ReactViewGroup) view).getOverflow();)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am having an issue with `react-native-gesture-handler`. Whenever I link my `react-native-gesture-handler` to my project it stops working and shows this error. But after unlinking `react-native-gesture-handler` from my project the application work fine. But as I need to navigate from several screens, I need gesture handler.

First I thought it was the problem of the `react-native` version as I was using `react-native` version 0.57.0 but it's not working on 0.58.0 and 0.55.4 either.

```
package com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react;

import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.facebook.react.uimanager.PointerEvents;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactPointerEventsView;
import com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.PointerEventsConfig;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.ViewConfigurationHelper;

public class RNViewConfigurationHelper implements ViewConfigurationHelper {

  @Override
  public PointerEventsConfig getPointerEventsConfigForView(View view) {
    PointerEvents pointerEvents;
    pointerEvents = view instanceof ReactPointerEventsView ?
            ((ReactPointerEventsView) view).getPointerEvents() :
            PointerEvents.AUTO;

    // Views that are disabled should never be the target of pointer events. However, their children
    // can be because some views (SwipeRefreshLayout) use enabled but still have children that can
    // be valid targets.
    if (!view.isEnabled()) {
      if (pointerEvents == PointerEvents.AUTO) {
        return PointerEventsConfig.BOX_NONE;
      } else if (pointerEvents == PointerEvents.BOX_ONLY) {
        return PointerEventsConfig.NONE;
      }
    }

    switch (pointerEvents) {
      case BOX_ONLY: return PointerEventsConfig.BOX_ONLY;
      case BOX_NONE: return PointerEventsConfig.BOX_NONE;
      case NONE: return PointerEventsConfig.NONE;
    }

    return PointerEventsConfig.AUTO;
  }

  @Override
  public View getChildInDrawingOrderAtIndex(ViewGroup parent, int index) {
    if (parent instanceof ReactViewGroup) {
      return parent.getChildAt(((ReactViewGroup) parent).getZIndexMappedChildIndex(index));
    }
    return parent.getChildAt(index);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewClippingChildren(ViewGroup view) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 && !view.getClipChildren()) {
        if (view instanceof ReactViewGroup) {
            String overflow = ((ReactViewGroup) view).getOverflow();
            return "hidden".equals(overflow);
        }
        return false;
      }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try manual linking.

Also check this issue out :
https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/205

Answer (score 1):

If you get the problem in Android, but not iOS, it could be that you need to add a polyfill for symbols.  I can't remember where I found this, but I have used it in my own projects and it works.  Just stick it in your index.js:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  if (typeof Symbol === 'undefined') {
    if (Array.prototype['@@iterator'] === undefined) {
      Array.prototype['@@iterator'] = function() {
        let i = 0;
        return {
          next: () => ({
            done: i >= this.length,
            value: this[i++]
          })
        };
      };
    }
  }
}
```